# Show $\partial _x \int_{(x_0, y_0)}^{(x,y)}P(s,t)ds + Q(s,t)dt = P(x,y)$

Tags: reference-request, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

There is a theorem from advanced calculus that I'm trying to prove. Suppose $P(x,y)$, $Q(x,y) \in C^2$ on a simply connected domain $D$, and suppose that $P_y = Q_x$ (i.e. $\omega = Pdx + Qdy$ is closed), we have that

$$\partial _x \int_{(x_0, y_0)}^{(x,y)}P(s,t)ds + Q(s,t)dt = P(x,y)  \\
\partial _y \int_{(x_0, y_0)}^{(x,y)}P(s,t)ds + Q(s,t)dt = Q(x,y).$$

(Note the integral is well-defined since $\omega$ closed means that the integral is path-independent.) I looked for a proof of this property of the derivatives but didn't find it. If anyone could provide a reference or a quick demonstration, it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the integral be independent of the path joining two points $(x,y),~~(x_0,y_0)$ then we know that $P_y=Q_x$. Of course being in $C^2$ guarantees us these partial derivatives are continuous. Also the later identity tells us that $\omega$ is an exact differential, i.e. that there exists a function $\phi(x,y)$ such that $$d\phi=\omega$$ Indeed; $$\phi_x=P,~~\phi_y=Q$$ Now if the path $C$ is the curve from fixed point $(x_0,y_0)$ to point $(x,y)$, then $$\int_{(x_0, y_0)}^{(x,y)}P(s,t)ds + Q(s,t)dt =\int_C P(s,t)ds + Q(s,t)dt=\int_{(x_0, y_0)}^{(x,y)}d\phi=\phi(x,y)-c$$ in which $c=\phi(x_0,y_0)$ is a constant. I thik your results come clear.

Comment: A-ha! I forgot all closed differential forms on a simply connected domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are exact!

Comment: You're doing great work!